# How can I access the width of a JPG loaded inside a movieclip in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i'm trying to reproduce the bookshelf similar the one in this site: http://www.callis.com.br/

The books are PNG files that comes in several different sizes.

What I'm trying to accomplish is, after loading in several different movieclips (book0, book1, book2, ...) read their widths, calculate the gap necessary to push it, and then arrange the x value of each book.

Every time I try to access the width value, it says it's 0.

Here's a portion of my code, that's trying to do the trick.

Thanks in advance.

```
for (j=0; j < dados.livro.length(); j++){
    if(j<8){
        targetLivro = MovieClip(MovieClip(root).livros.getChildByName("livro"+(j)));            
    }else{
        targetLivro = MovieClip(MovieClip(root).getChildByName("livro"+(j)));
    }

    preparaLivro(targetLivro,dados.livro[j].imagem.text(),dados.livro[j].link.text());

    //larguraTotalLivrosSup += targetLivro.width;
    //trace(larguraTotalLivrosSup);
    trace("livro"+j+": ");
    trace("título:"+dados.livro[j].titulo.text());
    trace("imagem:"+dados.livro[j].imagem.text());
    trace("link:"+dados.livro[j].link.text());
}

//organiza a primeira estante

//
/*
for (i=0; i<largurasArray.length; i++){
    trace(largurasArray[i]);
}*/

var offset:Number = 20;
for (j=0; j<livros.numChildren; j++){
    //targetLivro = MovieClip(livros).getChildByName("livro"+(j));
    trace(livros.getChildAt(j).width);
}

function preparaLivro(livro:MovieClip, capa:String, url:String){
var capaLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var capaImageRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(capa);

var capaBitmapData:BitmapData;
var capaBitmap:Bitmap;
var capaLargura:Number = 0;

capaLoader.load(capaImageRequest);
capaLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void{
    capaBitmapData = new BitmapData(e.target.content.width, e.target.content.height);
    capaBitmapData.draw(capaLoader);
    capaBitmap = new Bitmap;
    capaBitmap.bitmapData = capaBitmapData;
    livro.y -= e.target.content.height;

    trace(e.target.content.width, e.target.content.height);
    livro.buttonMode = true;
    livro.addChild(capaBitmap);
    livro.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void{
          navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url), "_blank");
    });
    //trace(e.target.content.width);
});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate bitmap from `LoaderInfo(event.target).content` like:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png"));

function onComplete(event:Event):void
{
    var bitmapData:BitmapData =
        Bitmap(LoaderInfo(event.target).content).bitmapData;
}
```

Tracing `bitmapData.width` and `bitmapData.height` outputs:

> > width: 550, height: 190

Otherwise, if you want width / height from the loader, access loader's `contentLoaderInfo`:

```
var width:Number = loader.contentLoaderInfo.width;
var height:Number = loader.contentLoaderInfo.height;
```